# JSON to Python not working correcly

Tags: python, json, url, python-2.7, tastypie

I have the following json string

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 3
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Exercicios_EO_JorgeLoureiro-cópia-não.está.exactament.igual.pdf\n",
            "resource_uri": "/api/open/1/"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "api.py\n",
            "resource_uri": "/api/open/2/"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "models.py\n",
            "resource_uri": "/api/open/3/"
        }
    ]
}
```

which i get from doing a server call and reading the response

```
response = url2.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/open/?format=json")
data = response.read()
```

However, when i load it from json to python via

```
res = json.loads(data)
```

i get, from printing res:

```
{u'meta': {u'previous': None, u'total_count': 3, u'offset': 0, u'limit': 20, u'next': None}, u'objects': [{u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/1/', u'id': 1, u'name': u'Exercicios_EO_JorgeLoureiro-c\xf3pia-n\xe3o.est\xe1.exactament.igual.pdf\n'}, {u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/2/', u'id': 2, u'name': u'api.py\n'}, {u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/3/', u'id': 3, u'name': u'models.py\n'}]}
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 3}, "objects": [{"id": 1, "name": "Exercicios_EO_JorgeLoureiro-cópia-não.está.exactament.igual.pdf\n", "resource_uri": "/api/open/1/"}, {"id": 2, "name": "api.py\n", "resource_uri": "/api/open/2/"}, {"id": 3, "name": "models.py\n", "resource_uri": "/api/open/3/"}]}


{u'meta': {u'previous': None, u'total_count': 3, u'offset': 0, u'limit': 20, u'next': None}, u'objects': [{u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/1/', u'id': 1, u'name': u'Exercicios_EO_JorgeLoureiro-c\xf3pia-n\xe3o.est\xe1.exactament.igual.pdf\n'}, {u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/2/', u'id': 2, u'name': u'api.py\n'}, {u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/3/', u'id': 3, u'name': u'models.py\n'}]}
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 3}, "objects": [{"id": 1, "name": "Exercicios_EO_JorgeLoureiro-cópia-não.está.exactament.igual.pdf\n", "resource_uri": "/api/open/1/"}, {"id": 2, "name": "api.py\n", "resource_uri": "/api/open/2/"}, {"id": 3, "name": "models.py\n", "resource_uri": "/api/open/3/"}]}


{u'meta': {u'previous': None, u'total_count': 3, u'offset': 0, u'limit': 20, u'next': None}, u'objects': [{u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/1/', u'id': 1, u'name': u'Exercicios_EO_JorgeLoureiro-c\xf3pia-n\xe3o.est\xe1.exactament.igual.pdf\n'}, {u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/2/', u'id': 2, u'name': u'api.py\n'}, {u'resource_uri': u'/api/open/3/', u'id': 3, u'name': u'models.py\n'}]}
```

which is like 3 copies of what I really wanted, which is just that json string to python.

Any clue of what might be going on?

Thanks in advance

Here is the full code

```
response = url2.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/open/?format=json")
data = response.read()
print data
print "\n"
res = json.loads(data)
print res
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the way you print it.

Comment: Im just doing 'print res'

Comment: Can you show the code you use to print?

Comment: Are you trying (by any chance) to iterate through the objects and printing the whole `res` thing?

Comment: Just added the full code

Comment: Is that full code you just added inside a function that gets called 3 times?

Comment: Oh god, just noticed it does... So bad from me, thanks!

Comment: [works fine for me](http://pastebin.com/etct33Ac), maybe you should check what you get in response once again? Maybe you append to something that is not re-initialized?